# How hashset memory overhead depends on objects size?

Tags: c#, hashset

How hashset memory overhead depends on objects size? And what if objects have different size?

Answer (score 3):

The size of the HashSet is going to be related to the size of a **variable** of the type of objects that the HashSet holds.  So for all reference types, that's the size of a reference, regardless of which type it is.

> And what if objects have different size?

A HashSet can only store objects of one type, so they *can't* have a different size.  They must all be the same size.

Comment: *A HashSet can only store objects of one type*, unless you use a base class (or `object`)...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair They'll all be of the same compile time type, regardless of their runtime type.  The runtime type is irrelevant in this context.

Comment: Fair enough! I completely forgot about how generics are compiled, arrr...